# Shilov's Linear Algebra, Chapter 8, Problem 32

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, isometry

On page 244:

> 32. Let $Q$ be a linear operator acting in an $n$-dimensional Euclidean space $\mathbf R_n (n \geq 3)$. Suppose $Q$ does not change the area of any parallelogram, so that $$V[x, y] = V[Qx, Qy].$$ Show that $Q$ is an isometric operator.

The hint for this problem is:

> 32. Hint. It is sufficient to show that $Q$ is an isogonal operator (see Prob. 31). Assuming that there is a right angle which is not transformed into a right angle, construct a parallelogram whose area changes as a result of applying the operator $Q$.

Taking the approach suggested by the hint, we only need to prove $Q$ is an isogonal operator, that is, for any $x, y \in \mathbf R_n$, if $(x, y) = 0$, then $(Qx, Qy) = 0$. To prove it, the hint suggests proof by contradiction: assume that we have found a pair of vectors $x, y \in \mathbf R_n$ with $(x, y) = 0$, that is, being orthogonal, but $(Qx, Qy) \neq 0$. Then, construct a parallelogram (i.e., another pair of vectors $a, b \in \mathbf R_n$) whose area does not preserve across the transformation, that is, $V[a, b] \neq V[Qa, Qb]$. But, even after a whole week contemplating, I still don't know how to construct such a parallelogram. Am I missing something? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This hint does not appear on Dover's reprint (1977) of Prentice Hall's English translation (1971) of Shilov's book. What edition of the book are you reading?

Comment: @user1551 The edition I'm reading is the same. The hint is on page 370.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see this hint in Dover's reprint of Shilov's book. Anyway, I think the problem can be solved easily without that hint.

Since $Q^TQ$ is real symmetric, it has an orthonormal eigenbasis $u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_n$. Let $Q^TQu_i=\lambda_iu_i$. Then $\lambda_i=u_i^TQ^TQu_i=\|Qu_i\|^2\ge0$ and
$$
1=V[u_i,u_j]=V[Qu_i,Qu_j]=\sqrt{[u_i|u_j]^TQ^TQ[u_i|u_j]}=\sqrt{\lambda_i\lambda_j}
$$
for every $i\ne j$. Hence $\lambda_i=1$ for every $i$, meaning that $Q^TQ=I$, i.e. $Q$ is an isometry.