# Linear operators that preserve the norm of cross product

Tags: linear-algebra, cross-product

$\times: \mathbb{R}^3 \times \mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R}^3$ cross product. Find all linear operators $T: \mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R}^3$ such that:

$$\|T(u) \times T(v)\|=\|u \times v\|$$

Can anyone give a hint to start, I can not leave the place.

Comment: You need $T(e_1)$, $T(e_2)$ and $T(e_3)$ to be an orthogonal triad of unit vectors, oriented positively.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown are you sure about the orientation?

Comment: By applications, do you mean linear operators?

Comment: @J.G yes, linear transformations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that a singular $T$ does not satisfy the equation for all $u$ and $v$: As there is a $u_0$ with $Tu_0 = 0$ and $\|u_0\| = 1$. Extend $u_0$ to an orthonormal basis $\{u_0, v, w\}$ and you obtain that
$$ \|Tu_0 \times Tv\| = 0 \ne 1 = \|u_0 \times v\|.$$
Thus, $T$ must be invertible.

For an invertible $T$ you have following identity (cf [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Algebraic_properties), or [proof on page 11](https://www.owlnet.rice.edu/~fjones/chap7.pdf)):
$$ Tu\times Tv = (\det T)(T^{-1})^t(u\times v).$$

By cycling $u\times v$ through $e_1,e_2,e_3$, you obtain that $M = (\det T)(T^{-1})^t$ is orthogonal. In particular we have
$$ \pm 1 = \det M = (\det T)^3 (\det T)^{-1} = (\det T)^2. $$
That is, $T$ itself needs to be an orthogonal matrix.

Now, assume $T$ to be an orthogonal matrix. Then, for every $u,v$ we have
$$ \|Tu \times Tv\| = \|\pm 1 (T^t)^t (u \times v)\| = \|u\times v\|. $$
That is, it is also sufficient that $T$ is orthogonal.

Comment: Do you know a short demo for this identity or do you really have to open accounts?

Comment: @Lucas: I extended the answer with a link to the proof

Comment: This shows that if $T$ is as in the OP, then $T \in \mathbb{R} O(3)$. Shouldn't we also show that if $T \in \mathbb{R} O(3)$, then $T$ has the desired property? I think if we check this, we'll find that in fact $T \in O(3)$, i.e. the scale factor must be $\pm 1$.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins: Thx. Will update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Coincidentally, someone asked a very similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3458012) yesterday. Since that question is more general and its formulation is somewhat differently from yours, I will give a differently phrased answer below.

By the given condition and [Lagrange's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_identity), we have
\begin{aligned}
\det\left[\pmatrix{u^\top\\ v^\top}T^\top T\pmatrix{u&v}\right]
&=\det\left[\pmatrix{(Tu)^\top\\ (Tv)^\top}\pmatrix{Tu&Tv}\right]\\
&=\|T(u) \times T(v)\|^2\\
&=\|u \times v\|^2\\
&=\det\left[\pmatrix{u^\top\\ v^\top}\pmatrix{u&v}\right]
\end{aligned}
for every $u,v\in\mathbb R^3$. Since $T^\top T$ is positive semidefinite, its eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$ are nonnegative. So, if $u$ and $v$ are two orthonormal eigenvectors of $T^\top T$, the above equality implies that $\lambda_i\lambda_j=1$ for every $i\ne j$. Hence either $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda_3=1$. In turn $T^\top T=I$, i.e. $T$ is real orthogonal.

Conversely, if $T$ is real orthogonal, then
\begin{aligned}
\|T(u) \times T(v)\|^2
&=\det\left[\pmatrix{(Tu)^\top\\ (Tv)^\top}\pmatrix{Tu&Tv}\right]\\
&=\det\left[\pmatrix{u^\top\\ v^\top}T^\top T\pmatrix{u&v}\right]\\
&=\det\left[\pmatrix{u^\top\\ v^\top}\pmatrix{u&v}\right]\\
&=\|u \times v\|^2.
\end{aligned}

Answer (score 0):

If the norm is the one induced by Cartesian dot product, you can write the norm in Cartesian components:

$$||u\times v||=\sqrt{\epsilon_{ijk}u_jv_k\epsilon_{imn}u_mv_n}$$

Then using the identity
$$\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{imn}=\delta_{jm}\delta_{kn}-\delta_{jn}\delta_{km}$$

We have
$$||u\times v||=\sqrt{u_iu_iv_jv_j-u_iv_iu_jv_j}$$

If the transformation is linear
$$T(u)_i=R_{ij}u_j$$ so

$$||T(u)\times T(u)||=\sqrt{R_{ik}R_{im}R_{jp}R_{jq}(u_ku_mv_pv_q-u_kv_mu_pv_q)}$$

For this to be equal to $||u\times v||$ it must be $R_{ik}R_{im}=\pm\delta_{km}$, which I think can be visualized as $O(n)\times\mathbb Z_4$, as any orthogonal matrix multiplied by $\pm1,\pm i$ would do the job.

Edit: considering that the application is from $\mathbb R^3$ in itself only $O(n)$ is enough